# Converting SQL Server query to Big Query, WHERE ID IN Correlated Subquery, Performance is slow

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, correlated-subquery

I have this query in SQL Server and it works well. I have a need to convert this to BigQuery. This will return in SQL Server in about 2 minutes. If I try to run this in BQ, I can let it run for over 15 minutes with no results. I will kill the query then and try something else.

```
With B as (Select BA, CA, ED, ID From Dataset Group by BA, CA, ED, ID)

Select 
    D1.BA,
    D1.CA,
    D1.ED,
    count(Distinct D2.ID) B_AW
From 
    B D1 
Join 
    Dataset D2 on D1.ED = D2.ED and D1.CA = D2.CA 
Where  
    D2.ID in (select ID From B 
                   Where D1.BA = B.BA and  D1.ED = B.ED) 
Group by 
    D1.BA, D1.CA, D1.ED 
Order by 
    D1.BA, D1.CA, D1.ED
```

I have been looking at this trying to recreate the SQL Server query logic in BQ and I think that is where I am getting stuck...  I am just learning BQ and I approach every situation as if it were SQL Server.

Comment: 2 minutes is entirely too long in a regular query for nearly anything. How many rows does this return?

Comment: Instead of killing the query, let it run to completion, and then check out the "Execution Plan" from the "Details" tab in the UI. The [execution plan documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) explains what the stages mean. If you include a screenshot of it here, people can probably provide suggestions of why it would be slow.

Comment: I condense 314,784,138 down to 2,900 results.  Elliott, I am running said query now and will let it run to the end

Comment: Update, it has been processing for over 3 hours and still running....  Sheesh!

Comment: The query failed with an internal error after 6 hours...  back to the drawing board...

Comment: If I'm not wrong, even if the query failed, you should be able to see the Execution Plan mentioned by @ElliottBrossard, so maybe you can share it to have further details. Also, let me share with you this set of documentation pages for [Optimizing Query Performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview). There you will be able to find some general guidelines on how to optimize query performance for the best usage of BigQuery. By seeing your query, you should more specifically be careful with JOIN and ORDER BY operations, which can consume high resources.

Comment: Also, do you have more details about the *internal error* with which the query finally failed?